# Borderless Entry difficult to focus

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I created a custom control based on an Entry which should not have a Border around it under **iOS**, but a linea beneath.

**BorderlessEntry**

```
namespace OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomEntry
{
    public class BorderlessEntry : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

In **App.xaml**, I used the following handler:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(BorderlessEntry), (handler, view) =>
{
    if (view is BorderlessEntry)
    {
#if __ANDROID__
        handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#elif __IOS__
        handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
        handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
#endif
    }
});
```

**Placed it in a StackLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Converters"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomEntry"
             x:Class="OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.FoodItemInputView"
             x:Name="this">

    
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 0, 5, 0" />
        </Style>
        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertBoolValueConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>
    

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto" BindingContext="{x:Reference this}" Margin="20, 0, 20, 20">
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Text="{Binding NameLabelString}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding IsOptionalLabelString}" FontSize="12" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
            <!-- Different type of Entry platform specific -->
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
                <On Platform="Android">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Entry x:Name="androidEntryControl" Text="{Binding EntryInput, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}}" Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderString}" Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardSetting}" Focused="EntryControl_Focused"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </On>
                <On Platform="iOS">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <!--Focused="EntryControl_Focused"-->
                        <controls:BorderlessEntry x:Name="iosEntryControl" Background="Wheat" Margin="10, -15, 10, 0" Text="{Binding EntryInput, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}}" Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderString}" Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardSetting}" Focused="EntryControl_Focused"/>
                        <!--<Entry x:Name="iosEntryControl" Background="Wheat" Margin="10, -15, 10, 0" Text="{Binding EntryInput, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}}" Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderString}" Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardSetting}" Focused="EntryControl_Focused"/>-->
                        <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="DarkBlue" Margin="10, 5, 10, 0">
                            <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="EntryLineTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                            </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                        </BoxView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </On>                
            </OnPlatform>
            
            <Label x:Name="labelErrorMessage" Text="{Binding NameLabelString}" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding InputValid, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolValueConverter}}" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
            <Label Text="{Binding MeasurementUnitString}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        </StackLayout>        
    </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

Then it is used within a ContentPage as a CustomControl having the BorderlessEntry inside:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">

    <!-- ScrollView stacked on top -->
    <Border x:Name="ManageItemBorder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" VerticalOptions="Start">

        <Grid>                
            <ScrollView x:Name="InnerScrollView" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <StackLayout>

                    <Label Text="{Binding ManageItemHeading}" Style="{StaticResource BorderHeadline}"/>


                    <controls:ItemInputView NameLabelString="ManageItem_ProductNameLabel"
                                                IsOptionalLabelString="ManageItem_MandatoryLabelString"
                                                PlaceholderString="ManageItem_ProductNamePlaceholder"
                                                EntryInput="{Binding Item.Name}"
                                                InputValid="{Binding NameInputValid, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                x:Name="firstContentView" />                        

                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>                
        </Grid>

    </Border>

</Grid>
```

When I do this, it is hardly possible for me to set focus to the BorderlessEntry when clicking it. I can't tell why, but sometimes after clicking several times it finally got the focus but I can't tell where I have to click to set the focus every time.

First of all I thought it is due to the negative margin to place the BorderLessEntry a bit more upwards. Then I thought it might be the problem that the BoxView actually got the focus. I introduced a TapGestureRecognizer for the BoxView and focused the BorderlessEntry when tapped. Unfortunately, without effect.

What is the reason it hardly wants to get the focus and is there a workaround?

Comment: On the native code try using BecomeFirstResponder on iOS for the Entry, Its a method you will find once you access the PlatformView

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it is the same behavior. Navigating with Tab when working in Simulator works, though. But, I already deployed it to my iPhone and also there I can't click into the Entries correctly.

Comment: Well you can use this https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls if you want...

Comment: I also set HeightRequest to 30 for the BorderlessEntry and seems to have a better responsiveness to clicks. Strangely enough there seem to be areas along the width of the Entry where it does not respond to my clicks. First of all, I thought I should maybe click directly on a character of the Placeholder, but somehow it also seems not to be the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have set a negative margin. This margin goes beyond the control and that is why you only get focus on the lower edge.

```xaml
    <controls:BorderlessEntry x:Name="iosEntryControl" Background="Wheat" Margin="10, -15, 10, 0" Text="{Binding EntryInput, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}}" Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderString}" Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardSetting}" Focused="EntryControl_Focused"/>
```

Comment: That's it - I moved the negative Margin to the parent StackLayout and made a HeightRequest accordingly so that the control is actually higher, which helped, too!
Thank you very much for your help!